# Android GPS get driving car speed

Tags: java, android, gps

How do my `android` cellphone get the a driving car speed from GPS?
Can you give me an example which it can get car location from GPS and get speed?

Any advice is a help.
Thank you very much.

Comment: i googled it and found a lot of examples

Comment: [The Basics](http://www.cimt.plymouth.ac.uk/projects/mepres/book8/bk8i18/bk8_18i2.htm) - So while you are moving - you are covering distance and to cover this distance time is required. All you need to know is how much distance you travel and in what time. Tally Ho!

Comment: @Skynet Nice thought but wrong. See my answer.

Comment: @AlexWien thank you for correcting me and providing a much better solution :)

Answer (score 5):

The location has an attribute speed which you get by getSpeed() method.

The GPS receiver chip determines speed NOT by distance and time relation.
It uses the Doppler Shift Effect, which gives more precise speed.
The higher the speed, the more acurate it is. Under 10km/h it does not work well.

Comment: Wow thanks mate, that just increased my knowledge :)

Comment: can you give us an example please sir, if possible

Answer (score 1):

```
    // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Define a listener that responds to location updates
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            location.getLatitude();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Current speed:" + location.getSpeed(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                Bundle extras) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
    };
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
            0, locationListener);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using android [locationmanager](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)  you can get latest last known [location](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) and in Location class [getSpeed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getSpeed%28%29) method is there which will gve speed

```
the speed if it is available, in meters/second over ground.

If this location does not have a speed then 0.0 is returned.
```

Another way is find the distance between two location using location manager & provider  and Location has one method to get distance in meter [distanceTo(Location)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo(android.location.Location))

Convert Distance to meter and get the time From Location Class using [getTime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getTime%28%29) and apply speed formula (speed = distance/time)