# How do I get walking speed using GPS?

Tags: android, gps

I am trying to track my accurate walking speed. I am using the `getSpeed()` method of the `LocationManager` class. The problem is, the speed is not accurate, also answered by **AlexWien** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28044261/android-gps-get-driving-car-speed) . Wein claims "The higher the speed, the more acurate it is. Under 10km/h it does not work well." So what would be the most precise way to do this if getSpeed is not built for precision? I did not stumble upon anything else yet.

```
// Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // Define a listener that responds to location updates
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            location.getLatitude();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Current speed:" + location.getSpeed(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                Bundle extras) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
    };
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
            0, locationListener);
```

PS:: I understand that both Location and Fine Location permissions are required in this case.

Comment: |You did your homework. You know the answers. Accept you cannot get it precise.

Comment: I believe the "built in" speed is just an approximation calculated of two samples, you could just do your own approximation by taking samples each ~10 seconds and calculate the average speed (length walked in 1 minute or so). That should give you a value that isn't exact, but a good approximation for most purposes.
To get a more accurate value you could use the accelerometer.